# How to build a Form Group that reacts to conditions?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form group created as such:

```
this.formGroupName = this.formBuilder.group({
  control1: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  control2: this.formBuilder.group({
    innerControl1: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    innerControl2: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
  }),
  control3: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
});
```

Normally my user is going to input something for control1 and control3 at all times, and control2 is not required to complete the form. However if the user  selects an additional option, I want control2 to also be required.

How would I go about achieving such functionality? Are there built-in tools? I tried using an if statement inside the formBuilder, but that doesn't work.

Comment: How the user will select that additional option? Is it another control inside the form?

Comment: Yes it will be a radio button that determines what form inputs to show to the user, with this radio button being required in the form group.

Comment: I have updated my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setValidators()` function to add validators dynamically and `clearValidators()` function to remove them. Additionally, you may need to call `updateValueAndValidity()` function to force the validators act immediately.

Now, if your condition is triggered by an external code (something that is not a control of the form), try the sample code:

```
if(some-condition){
   this.formGroupName.controls.control2.setValidators([Validators.required]);
   this.formGroupName.controls.control2.updateValueAndValidity();
}else{
   this.formGroupName.controls.control2.clearValidators();
}
```

On the other hand, if the condition is dependent on a control of the form, subscribe to the `valueChanges` of the that control. try this sample code:

```
this.formGroupName.controls.anotherControl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {

    if(val){
        this.formGroupName.controls.control2.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.formGroupName.controls.control2.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
    else{
        this.formGroupName.controls.control2.clearValidators();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I would've never thought to subscribe to the changes. I do believe this works.